# ant: target to list processes

Tags: bash, unix, ant

I've done some basic targets in ant and I'm now trying to do something even more basic.

My goals is to have a target for "debug" where I can just get the result of a certain call to ps command.

for example if I call in my bash manually:

```
$ ps -ef | grep /bin/bash
502       1373     1  0 05:28 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash MyScript.sh /data/dir  > MyScript.log
502      32314 31196  0 09:42 pts/0    00:00:00 grep /bin/bash
```

I'm trying a basic target, that does not seem to work.

```
  <target name="list-processes" depends="init">
        <exec executable="ps" spawn="false" output="Yes">
           <arg line=" -ef | grep /bin/bash" />
        </exec>
  </target>
```

I've tried several variations, removing the output, running without args, etc. but seem to be a bit lost.
I can have a script and run it, and probably redirect the result to a file, but I would really like to have it just in the standard out and without doing a script for it. Mainly because I think it should be possible.

I'm running on redhat and i do know that i should protect the target with the os family.

edit: forgot to post the output of my target:

```
[user@instance ]$ ./script.sh target.list-processes
09:47:28.605: EXECUTE COMMAND 'target.list-processes' [Target Rev. c057925fc5b586013fd4ea903a65115dd42d4ceb]
09:47:29.190: Result: 1
09:47:29.192: COMMAND 'target.list-processes' SUCCESSFUL (execution time: 0 seconds)
[user@instance]$
```

I do know that I'm getting one that is error, but If i run without parameters it returns nothing, not 0 nor 1, nor nothing

edit2:
I'm a bit closer to what I wanted to get but still not there.

```
  <target name="list-processes" depends="init">
    <exec executable="ps" osfamily="unix" outputproperty="list-processes-output" resultproperty="list-processes-result">
      <arg line="-ef" />
    </exec>
    <echo message="exec ps result: ${list-processes-result}" />
    <exec executable="grep" osfamily="unix" outputproperty="grep-processes-output" resultproperty="grep-processes-result">
      <arg line="bash" />
    </exec>
    <echo message="${grep-processes-output}" />
    <echo message="exec grep result: ${grep-processes-result}" />
  </target>
```

the list or processes is ok, but I don't know how to use it in the grep, because I'm don't have it in a file.

ok, finally i got a solution, but to be honest not really pleased, but it does the trick.
if there are some better solutions, please let me know

```
10:24:27.268: exec ps result: 0
10:24:27.676: 502       1373     1  0 05:28 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash Script.sh /data/dir > Script.log
10:24:27.677: exec grep result: 0
```

this is the final target

```
  <target name="list-processes" depends="init">
    <exec executable="ps" osfamily="unix" outputproperty="list-processes-output" resultproperty="list-processes-result">
      <arg line="-ef" />
    </exec>
    <echo message="exec ps result: ${list-processes-result}" />
    <echo message="${list-processes-output}" file="processes.txt"/>
    <exec executable="grep" osfamily="unix" outputproperty="grep-processes-output" resultproperty="grep-processes-result">
      <arg line="/bin/bash processes.txt" />
    </exec>
    <echo message="${grep-processes-output}" />
    <echo message="exec grep result: ${grep-processes-result}" />
  </target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Ant script that runs `ps` and then uses a `<linecontains>` filter to "grep" the output:

```
<project name="ant-exec-ps-grep" default="run">
    <target name="run">
        <exec executable="ps">
            <arg value="-ef"/>
            <redirector outputproperty="list-processes-output">
                <outputfilterchain>
                    <linecontains>
                        <contains value="/bin/bash"/>
                    </linecontains>
                </outputfilterchain>
            </redirector>
        </exec>
        <echo>list-processes-output: ${list-processes-output}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

This script only launches a single process (`ps`) rather than two (`ps` and `grep`), so this script will be faster. Further, the script doesn't generate any temporary files that need to be cleaned up.